# Problems with Python password checker

Tags: python, string, function, file, passwords

I have created a password checker in Python.  Here is the code that I have used:

```
import easygui as eg

def pword():
    global password
    global lower
    global upper
    global integer
    password = eg.enterbox(msg="Please enter your password")
    length = len(password)
    print(length)
    lower = sum([int(c.islower()) for c in password])
    print(length)
    upper = sum([int(c.isupper()) for c in password])
    print (upper)
    integer = sum([int(c.isdigit()) for c in password])
    print (integer)

def length():
    global password
    if len(password) < 6:
        eg.msgbox(msg="Your password is too short, please try again")
    elif len(password) > 12:
        eg.msgbox(msg="Your password is too long, please try again")

def strength():
    global lower
    global upper
    global integer
    if (lower) < 1:
        eg.msgbox(msg="Please use a mixed case password with lower case    letters")
    elif (upper) < 1:
        eg.msgbox(msg="Please use a mixed case password with UPPER clase letters")
    elif (integer) < 1:
        eg.msgbox(msg="Please try adding a number")
    else:
        eg.msgbox(msg="Strength Assessed - Your password is ok")

while True:
    pword()
    length()
    strength()

answer = eg.choicebox(title="Try again?",msg="Would you like to try again?", choices=("Yes","No"))
if answer !="Yes":
    sys.exit()
```

When I go to run the module it just comes up with the following message:

RESTART: C:\Users\PGUSER72\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python password 8.py

When I restart it just says RESTART - Shell

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please.

Comment: First of all, clean up your indentation, then fix up the unnecessary and unsafe usage of globals

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your indentation

Your code works, tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**EDIT:**

Also tested on Windows 7 32bit python 2.7.12
[image]

Everything works fine. How are you running your script?

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is using Windows.

Comment: I just added a test report on windows